# <br> tag alternative for breaking text line

Tags: html, text, browser, autoresize

Is there anyway to add a tag similar to a `<br>` tag that doesn't break a line of text straight away but only  when the browser is resized and it needs to? So to create a point in which the line breaks when it's resized to a smaller browser window?

Comment: I don't understand. Text wraps naturally without any additional markup.

Comment: Can you post the HTML that is giving you trouble?  What you describe is the default behavior, but it's possible to overwrite it with `float: left` and/or `white-space: nowrap`.

Comment: Sorry,Explain you question in brief Its cant easily under stable.

Comment: For example.    There is some text here that makes a sentence.   When the browser is resized down instead of the line break going in between the a and the word sentence. I want it to always break in between the words text and here :)

Comment: You should add clarifications to the question itself and present a real example there. Now it is rather difficult to see what you are asking. It seems that you would like to *prevent* line breaks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to tell where the test should **not** break, by using unbreakable spaces in your code (the html code is `&nbsp;`) or using the css property `text-wrap: none;` for a specific portion of your document.

By using either or those two techniques you can say where your text will break for wrapping (use the `span` html element for the css technique), but it will be a bit ugly, and not very useful in most cases and I wouldn't recommend it unless you have a good reason to do it.

Comment: The `text-wrap` property is just at a draft level. The standard CSS way of preventing line breaks is `white-space: nowrap`.

Answer (score 0):

You could certainly use media queries to only show your line break below a certain screen size:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/hRL4S

```
br.my-class {display: none}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
     br.my-class {display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I usually use tables that resize, When to page is resized the text wrap usually works fine for this in html.

Comment: Tables should not be used for layout.